# What is the concept of mainthread handling the broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android

I have a question with respect to broadcast receiver and mainthread handling it.

If main thread is doing some computation(or you can say executing a code under a constructor or in a method) and broadcast receiver onReceive() is triggered? Which task will be picked up

1. Constructor/Method will complete its execution and then onReceive is called. (This is what my understanding is)
2. onReceive will be triggered first

Comment: I believe you understanding is correct.

Comment: This means, if the computation is taken for too long.. onReceive will be impacted with that. I don't got any proof of reading. Or MainThread takes the priority and execute that task first..

Answer (score 0):

**Constructor/Method will complete its execution and then onReceive is called**  should be the answer, because BroadcastReceivers are always called on the main thread.

> void onReceive (Context context, 
>                   Intent intent).
>
> This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving an 
>   Intent broadcast. During this time you can use the other methods on 
>   BroadcastReceiver to view/modify the current result values. This 
>   method is always called within the main thread of its process, unless 
>   you explicitly asked for it to be scheduled on a different thread 
>   using registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter, String,
>   android.os.Handler).

[More details here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are right....

1) First the execution of main thread will complete then only any pending task will be executed.

2) If main thread takes too long to complete its task it will simply  give an `exception` something like this :

> Application "AndroidThreadDemo" not responding.

Please see [this link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_Basic_Overview_of_Android_Threads_and_Thread_handlers) for more info.. I am sure it will help you.